# Apache2 shutdown when modifiying the 000-default.conf

Tags: apache, file, configuration

When I'm following the guide of installing the application maarchrm. It's demanded to include the line below in the configuration file '000-default.conf' :

```
# Application Maarch RM 
     Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf
```

But when I put it into the configuration file; I can't restart apache anymore. I can restart apache only when i delete the line i added to the file '000-default.conf'.

This is the code of the 000-default.conf file :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    # LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    # Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    # Application Maarch RM 
     Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

vhost.conf :

```
    # APP MaarchRM - Records Management
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Chemin vers le répertoire public web de Laabs
     DocumentRoot /var/www/laabs/web/

    # Nom du vhost (identique au nom associé à l'adresse IP dans le fichier host)
     ServerName maarchrm

    Options -Indexes 
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # DirectoryIndex dynamic.php

    # Rewrite URLs to route to frontal scripts 
    # when target is not an existing public resource
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]

    # Rewrite to dynamic frontal if no file extension
    # input: /route?args... 
    # output : http.php/route?args...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /http.php [QSA,L] 

    # Set environment variables for the application instance
    SetEnv LAABS_INSTANCE_NAME maarchRM
    SetEnv LAABS_APP maarchRM
    SetEnv LAABS_BUNDLES recordsManagement;documentManagement;digitalResource;medona;financialRecords;organization;audit;lifeCycle;archivesPubliques;contact;seda;auth;businessRecords
    # SetEnv LAABS_EXTENSIONS
    SetEnv LAABS_DEPENDENCIES repository;xml;html;localisation;datasource;sdo;json;fileSystem;authentication;logger;authorization
    SetEnv LAABS_PRESENTATION maarchRM

    SetEnv LAABS_CONFIGURATION "../data/maarchRM/conf/configuration.ini"
    SetEnv LAABS_LOG "../data/maarchRM/log.txt"
    SetEnv LAABS_TMP_DIR "../data/maarchRM/tmp"

    SetEnv LAABS_CONTENT_TYPES "url:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;html:text/html,application/xhtml+xml;xml:application/xml;json:application/json,application/javascript;soap:application/soap+xml;csv:text/csv"
    #SetEnv LAABS_CONTENT_LANGUAGES "fr:fr,fr-fr,fr-ca"
    SetEnv LAABS_CACHE_CONTROL "public, max-age=3600"

    #SetEnv LAABS_EXCEPTION_HANDLER
    #SetEnv LAABS_ERROR_HANDLER

    SetEnv LAABS_DATE_FORMAT "d-m-Y"
    SetEnv LAABS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT "Y-m-d\TH:i:s,u\Z"
    SetEnv LAABS_NUMBER_DECIMALS 2
    SetEnv LAABS_DEFAULT_URI recordsManagement/welcome/welcomePage
    SetEnv LAABS_ERROR_URI recordsManagement/welcome/error

    SetEnv LAABS_CRYPT_KEY mySecretKey
    SetEnv LAABS_CRYPT_CIPHER MCRYPT_BLOWFISH
    SetEnv LAABS_XML_NS "seda:fr:gouv:culture:archivesdefrance:seda:v1.0;medona:org:afnor:medona:1.0"
</VirtualHost>
```

I wish you have the solution for this problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: is there any file in `/var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf`?

Comment: No vhost is itself a file and doesn't have any.

Comment: if there's none `vhost.conf`  in `/var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/` then it is normal that you're apache will crash. Since it will give you an incorrent path. If you do `service apache2 status` you will see that the error is because apache is unable to find that vhost.conf

Comment: I said that vhost.conf exists, I thought you were talking about another file inside that path.

Comment: can you edit your question and post the actual /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf code? (remove senstive info please)

Comment: I need to see the vhost.conf file not the default

Comment: Done you can see it now

Comment: The startup logs for Apache should give the error. This will be the logs ``systemd`` or whatever has for applications when starting them, not the Apache error logs. At a guess you might not have ``mod_rewrite`` enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your default.conf comment these lines

```
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html 

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

By placing a # before each line

```
#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html 

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Then again restart your apache. This should do the trick

Control if your 000-default.conf looks like this (code in the exact same place).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
# LogLevel info ssl:warn

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
# Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
# Application Maarch RM 

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf
```

Comment: Even though I comment these lines, it still not working. the problem is in this line uncommented : Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf

Comment: did you place `Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf` before `</VirtualHost>`?

Comment: Yes I placed it but no result

Comment: does your `vhost.conf ` has `<VirtualHost *:80>` ? if not this include must be placed before VirtualHost (i edited the answer, check it out

Comment: sorry forgot to comment some stuff I re-edited the asnwer

Comment: @K.ossama after editing your question i saw that your code wasn't well implemented, the <virtualhost> tags were not showing properly in your question. I edited my answer the include must be added at the end of the file!

Comment: Thank u @Diogo Jesus for your answers. Now I can restart apache but I don't know if the line will be taken into consideration.let me ask you another question if you know how to do the installation. After adding the adress of maarch in etc/hosts, I find another 127.0.0.1 reserved for debian, so how can I start my application if 127.0.0.1 points always to debian. thanks

Comment: I've never used this application, send me the installation guide that you're using so I can see their config

Comment: guide installetion is in french, go to connexion a l'application part.                                          etc/hosts :                                                                           127.0.0.1       localhost debian
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters                                                                       Installation guide                                    https://wiki.maarch.org/Maarch_RM/Proc%C3%A9dure_d%27installation

Comment: is the server local? or is it in a hosted server? Is it virtual box? a server in your company/home or hosted ina datacenter?

Comment: no It's server local. I put the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148966/how-to-change-the-default-page-localhost-debian-to-run-an-application