# how to change the Default page localhost debian to run an application

Tags: debian, apache2, debian-jessie

In debian, I installed an application 'maarchrm'. at the end of the guide intallation it's demanded to add the line 127.0.0.1 to the file 'etc/hosts'.
inside this file we find these lines :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost debian
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

So when I add the line, It becomes like this :

```
127.0.0.1       maarchrm
127.0.0.1       localhost debian
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

the problem occurs when I want to run this application using the address 'http://maarchrm'. it takes me to 'apache2 debian default page'
here is the 000-default :

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    # LogLevel info ssl:warn

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    # Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
#</VirtualHost>
 Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf
```

how can I solve this and thanks in advance

Comment: comment this line `127.0.0.1       localhost debian` and post the result

Comment: I tried this but no result it still takes me to the default page

Answer (score 0):

Comment every line in 000-default.conf `<virtualhost *:80>` aswell. Something like this.

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
# LogLevel info ssl:warn

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
# Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
# Application Maarch RM 
#</VirtualHost>
Include /var/www/laabs/data/maarchRM/conf/vhost.conf
```

Then restart apache. This should solve it

---

### EDIT

Remove the index.html located in /var/www/html/ and run the following commands as root:

```
find /var/www/laabs/web/ -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 644
find /var/www/laabs/web/ -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 755
```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. maybe there is another trick.

Comment: Edit your question and post the actual 000-default.conf file with the # on every line. The thing is `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` is being called somewhere in the config that's why you're seeing apache default page.

Comment: just edited my question try it please and report the output

Comment: Sorry for not responding, I have just reinstalled the application and it's working like magic. thanks for your answers anyway :)